# How do I turn off the verbose logging in swagger-codegen?

Tags: swagger-codegen

I upgraded to swagger-codegen 3.0.10, and all of a sudden there's a ton of debugging output to the screen. There seems to be no command-line option to turn it off.

Does anyone know how to turn off the debugging output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Swagger-codegen uses [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) for logging, and so we need to change its config file.

Step 1: Create a file logback.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <logger name="io.swagger" level="warn"/>
</configuration>
```

Step 2: swagger-codegen is actually a script that invokes java with the appropriate jar. You can edit the command (or invoke java directly from the command line) and include the following in the command line:

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml
```

assuming logback.xml file is in your local directory. Of course, change the path if it's in a different directory.

For example:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml -jar /usr/local/Cellar/swagger-codegen/3.0.10/libexec/swagger-codegen-cli.jar ...[other options]
```

This will turn off the verbose output. You can set other levels as you like - just replace 'warn' in the logback.xml file.

Comment: I have no log shown anymore, even with `level="debug"`. Using `swagger-codegen 3.0.20`. Is it still working for you?

Comment: I have not upgraded, and am unlikely to in the near future. To be clear, I wanted to turn OFF the logging, which seems to be the opposite of what you want.

Checking the swagger codebase, I see this file. I suggest playing around with the params to see if it solves your problem.

swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/src/main/resources/logback.xml

Comment: Thanks, already played with this file and all possible configurations. It seems that using `-Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml` will turn off all logging as you said. The specified level is not respected at all.